# Let $p\geq 5$ be a prime. What are the real roots $x^p-p^px+p$ has?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

How many real roots does $x^p-p^px+p$ have, for some prime $p\geq 5$?  It's easy to see there are no rational roots by the Rational Roots Theorem.  $\sqrt{p}$ is also not a root.  Maybe I could tap into some Galois theory here, but I can't think of a way to explicitly find the real roots... I think I am missing something quite simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roots of the derivative of $f(x)=x^p - p^px + p$ are only $\pm p$. Since $f$ is an odd degree polynomial, this means that the function is increasing in $(-\infty,-p)$, decreasing in $(-p,p)$ and increasing in $(p,\infty)$.

Since $f(-p)>0$ and $f(p)<0$ then there's exactly one root in each interval.

Note that this is also valid for the prime $3$ (and actually for any odd integer grater than $1$).

Comment: Very nice!  I would have never thought to just use basic Calculus! Answer accepted :)
Thank you!